# Testing Links with protractor in my website

Tags: testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm testing a website - single page application using Angular.
I'm looking for the right way to test all the links in my site to make sure that:

1. I'm not getting to 404
2. I'm getting to the place I'm supposed to get

I could create a test and put all the links in it and the urls I expect to get. 
but it sounds like a lot of work and maintenance. can you think of a better way to do it?
thanks.

EDIT:
in other tests when I want to make sure that the link actually leads to the right place I use something like:

```
 browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//* [@id="navbar"]/ul/li[4]/a')).click();
 browser.getTitle().then(function (titleText) {
  console.log(titleText)  
  expect(titleText).toBe(" My Portal | Inbox page");
  });
```

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried and the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you only need to check `a` elements. You could grab all link elements, iterate through them to get their hrefs, and then click on each one. Assuming that you are doing nothing special with the elements, navgiating to the URL directly should be the same as clicking on the link.

Here's some code, which I haven't tried:

```
var urls = [];
var links = element.all(by.css('a')).then(function(links) {
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.getAttribute('href').then(function(href) {
      urls.push(href);
    });
});

// wait for all the links to be grabbed
browser.waitForAngular().then(function() {
  urls.forEach(function(url) {
      browser.get(url);
      checkBrowserState();
  });
});
```

Comment: looks nice. I will try it.

Comment: it's not really working. I'm getting 'TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not object'